# How can I implement the input of multiple regression in LSTM using keras?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

here is my code

```
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), 0])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

df = pd.read_csv('time_series.csv')
signal_data = df.Close.values.astype('float32')
signal_data = signal_data.reshape(len(df), 1)


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
signal_data = scaler.fit_transform(signal_data)

train_size = int(len(signal_data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(signal_data) - train_size)
# val_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - test_size
train = signal_data[0:train_size]
# val = signal_data[train_size:train_size+val_size]
test = signal_data[train_size+val_size:len(signal_data)]

x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
# x_val, y_val = create_dataset(val, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)


x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
# x_val = np.reshape(x_val, (x_val.shape[0], x_val.shape[1], 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
```

now I want to add `df.Open` and `df.High` and  `df.Low` and `df.Volume`

how can I implement this code?

Should I just add to the signal data? I'm wondering how to add data so that I can train multiple features in the signal data.

I don't know where and how to implement it. I need your help.

Your valuable opinions and thoughts will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please, provide a reproducible example with the complete code and we'll be able to help you :D. You need to include also the code of the LSTM implementation, which framework do you use, etc... Otherwise it is impossible to add something

Comment: here is full source https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/e1fc7d036356575f4d0799cdcebed90e

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, but I must load the data to be able to help. Can you at least provide a simple script mimicking the data set you have?

Comment: you can find last comment in git source url...
#kospi.csv is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13qyMDbl9EsBPE6asoXkH_73Y4QVGzaiUXyir94nN3VE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made several modifications to your code. This should work. In summary:

- I got fixed the lines of code where you were barcoding the selection of the variable 0. Now, the target variable stands on the last position and the others in the previous ones
- I fixed the reshapes some of them were not needed and the others were fixed to keep all the dimensions
- I fixed the model input shape, now you have 5 variables instead of 1

My general recommendations:

- I would not use `MinMaxScaler`, it is dangerous because a single outlier can disturb all your distribution. Instead, use `StandardScaler`. More info here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html
- I would scale the data afterwards, when the `train_x`, `test_x` and their `y` respective counterparts are built. The reason why is because you are computing the statistics for scaling the data using the train and test set, i.e. future information. This is by all the means different to what you'll find when you try to run your code in a real situation. I.e. you'll have to scale the new data with past statistics. It is better to build a test set as close to the reality as possible.
- How do you know that your model is big enough to model your data? I would get rid of the dropouts and run the model to see if it can overfit the data. If the model can overfit to the train data, it means that the model is big enough and you can start regularising your model to enhance generalisation. More info in this book: https://www.deeplearning.ai/machine-learning-yearning/
- In the model `metrics` you choose `accuracy`, which is a classification metric. I would use one according to my type of problem (regression): for example "Mean Absolute Error".

I hope I managed to help you :D

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Conv2D, Reshape, TimeDistributed, Flatten, Conv1D,ConvLSTM2D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth=True

sess = tf.Session(config=config)
def create_dataset(signal_data, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(signal_data) - look_back):
        dataX.append(signal_data[i:(i + look_back), :])
        dataY.append(signal_data[i + look_back, -1])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)


look_back = 20



df = pd.read_csv('kospi.csv')
signal_data = df[["Open", "Low", "High", "Volume", "Close"]].values.astype('float32')


scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
signal_data = scaler.fit_transform(signal_data)



train_size = int(len(signal_data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - int(len(signal_data) * 0.05)
val_size = len(signal_data) - train_size - test_size
train = signal_data[0:train_size]
val = signal_data[train_size:train_size+val_size]
test = signal_data[train_size+val_size:len(signal_data)]



x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_val, y_val = create_dataset(val, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)




model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None, 5),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(None, 5)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(1))




model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


model.summary()
hist = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

trainScore = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=0)
model.reset_states()
print('Train Score: ', trainScore)
valScore = model.evaluate(x_val, y_val, verbose=0)
model.reset_states()
print('Validataion Score: ', valScore)
testScore = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
model.reset_states()
print('Test Score: ', testScore)



p = model.predict(x_test)


print(mean_squared_error(y_test, p))

import matplotlib.pyplot as pplt

pplt.plot(y_test)
pplt.plot(p)
pplt.legend(['testY', 'p'], loc='upper right')
pplt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer with your kind explanation.

Comment: May I ask you one question?
If I use `MinMaxscaler`, the loss is low. That means good performance.
Nevertheless, should you use `StandardScaler` for stock data? because a single outlier can disturb all my distribution

Comment: I think that generally `MinMaxScaler` is a bad idea. Imagine you have a time series which has an outlier (e.g. [2500, 2350, 2680, ... 9989, 2873, 2284]) in this case, either the max or the minimum will be overestimated, you'll rescale by them and the distribution will be very biased. If you rather use `StandardScaler`, this outlier would  almost no affect the normalisation and the final distribution of your data. It is also important to notice that if you calculate the `max` and `min` params using the former method, in these you can have values out of the 0-1 range, and the behaviour of...

Comment: ... the model will be unexpected.

Comment: I have a new question If you don't mind me asking for help.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/57550965/11309950